# Struggling to extract part of beautiful soup result set

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a url from a `bs4.element.ResultSet`. I have distilled the result set down to the following.

```
dirty_true_url = [<meta content="https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/AK-103_7.62x39_assault_rifle" property="og:url"/>]
```

Obviously, the url is present in the `meta content` tag, and is a 'pedia.com page.

In case it is required, this is the `type` of object I am handling:

```
type(dirty_true_url) #bs4.element.ResultSet
type(dirty_true_url[0]) #bs4.element.Tag
```

I have tried to obtain the url using variations of the following:

```
print(dirty_true_url('content'))
print(dirty_true_url[0]('content'))
print(dirty_true_url[0]('meta', {'content'}))
print(dirty_true_url[0]('meta', {'content' : ''}))
print(dirty_true_url[0]('meta', {'content' : 'https://'}))
print(dirty_true_url[0]('meta', {'content' : 'https://.*'}))

from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse
parameters = parse_qs(urlparse(dirty_true_url).query)
print( parameters['https'][0] )
```

How can I extract the content/url from my soup?

---

If necessary, the following code can be used to obtain `dirty_true_url`:

```
#modules
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import StringIO

#body of code that gets the page
pseudo_temp_weapon_page_url = 'https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=AK-103&redirect=yes'
pseudo_temp_weapon_page = requests.get(pseudo_temp_weapon_page_url)
pseudo_temp_weapon_soup = BeautifulSoup(pseudo_temp_weapon_page.content, 'html.parser')
pseudo_temp_weapon_soup_as_string = StringIO(str(pseudo_temp_weapon_soup))
pseudo_temp_weapon_soup_parsed = BeautifulSoup\
    (pseudo_temp_weapon_soup_as_string, 'html.parser')


#Snippet of html containing URL
dirty_true_url = pseudo_temp_weapon_soup_parsed.find_all(property="og:url")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
print(dirty_true_url[0].get('content'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary. [`docs`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)

```
dirty_true_url = pseudo_temp_weapon_soup_parsed.find_all(property="og:url")
print(dirty_true_url[0]['content'])
```

**output:**

```
'https://escapefromtarkov.gamepedia.com/AK-103_7.62x39_assault_rifle'
```